# Replicating a JSON file in C#

Tags: c#, json

For a project that I am working on, I'm trying to replicate a JSON file that was created with JavaScript in C#. For this project I have to label images before I can run them through a Neural Network, and to annotate those images I use [via](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/software/via/). The resulting JSON file looks like this.

```json
"Dog.png173732": {
    "filename": "Dog.png",
    "size": 173732,
    "regions": [
        {
            "shape_attributes": {
                "name": "polygon",
                "all_points_x": [
                    189,
                    192,
                    229,
                    230
                ],
                "all_points_y": [
                    2,
                    148,
                    148,
                    2
                ]
            },
            "region_attributes": {
                "Animal": "Dog"
            }
        }
    ],
    "file_attributes": {}
},
```

To replicate this in C#, I created a class with multiple getters and setters, while using the Nuget package [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), to serialize my JSON.

```cs
public class Animal
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? Size { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<Animal> Regions { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<Animal> Shape_attributes { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<int> All_points_x { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<int> All_points_y { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<Animal> Region_attributes { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Animal { get; set; }


    public void CreateJSON()
    {
        string output = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) +
            @"\source\repos\Testing\";

        var root = new Animal()
        {
            Filename = "Dog.png",
            Size = 173732,
            Regions = new List<Animal>()
            {
                new Animal()
                {
                    Size = null,

                    Shape_attributes = new List<Animal>()
                    {
                        new Animal()
                        {
                            Name = "polygon",
                            All_points_x = All_points_x,
                            All_points_y = All_points_y
                        }
                    },

                    Region_attributes = new List<Animal>()
                    {
                        new Animal()
                        {
                            Animal = "Dog"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });

        File.WriteAllText(output + "testing.json", json);
    }
```

Once I execute the following code, my output is as follows.

```json
{
    "filename": "Dog.png",
    "size": 173732,
    "regions": [
        {
            "shape_attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "polygon",
                    "all_points_x": [
                        389,
                        43
                    ],
                    "all_points_y": [
                        33,
                        215
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "region_attributes": [
                {
                    "animal": "Dog"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I adjust my code to better replicated via's Json file? Is there a better way that I could be doing things?

Comment: I am not going to play 'find whats different in these 2 things', but you could feed the original JSON to VS and it will create the correct classes for you.

Comment: You are pretty close, it's just the `Animal` inside region attributes and the fact that the filename and filesize are a property on the parent object that are missing (and the `file_attributes`. Do you only have to write out the information, or do you also have to read it in? If you have to write it out, just add `JsonProperty("Animal")` and serialize `IDictionary<string,object>` where the dictionary has your key, and the object is the animal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this...

First I created classes for each of the inner bits of your structure:

```
public class RegionAttributes
{
    public string Animal { get; set; }
}

public class ShapeAttributes
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<int> all_points_x { get; set; }
    public List<int> all_points_y { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public ShapeAttributes shape_attributes { get; set; }
    public RegionAttributes region_attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Thing
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public List<Region> regions { get; set; }
    public dynamic file_attributes { get; set; }
}
```

You should be able to see that the hierarchy of these classes matches the hierarchy of your JSON.

Then I initialize one of these `Thing`s:

```
var thing = new Dictionary<string, Thing>
{
    {
        "Dog.png173732", new Thing
        {
            filename = "Dog.png",
            size = 173732,
            regions = new List<Region>
            {
                new Region
                {
                    shape_attributes = new ShapeAttributes
                    {
                        name = "polygon",
                        all_points_x = new List<int> {189, 192, 229, 230},
                        all_points_y = new List<int> {2, 148, 148, 2},
                    },
                    region_attributes = new RegionAttributes
                    {
                        Animal = "dog",
                    }
                }
            },
            file_attributes = new object()
        }
    }
};
```

Again, you can see the similarity of the structure in the code to the structure of the JSON.  Finally, I do this (using the Newtonsoft JSON package):

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing, Formatting.Indented);
```

This results in this string:

```
{
  "Dog.png173732": {
    "filename": "Dog.png",
    "size": 173732,
    "regions": [
      {
        "shape_attributes": {
          "name": "polygon",
          "all_points_x": [
            189,
            192,
            229,
            230
          ],
          "all_points_y": [
            2,
            148,
            148,
            2
          ]
        },
        "region_attributes": {
          "Animal": "dog"
        }
      }
    ],
    "file_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

I think that's a match.  You'll probably want to use attributes to get C#-ish names in the C# code and JSON-ish names in the JSON output.  But, there you go...

Comment: Thanks! Your dedication is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close to it, but your structure was missing. There are a couple of things you could look at, for example, the `NamingStrategy` that the json object is using is called [**SnakeCase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) and [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySnakeCase.htm) has a default implementation for this strategy.

To set the default convention, you could make it available through:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => {
    return new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
        },
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };
};
```

This then allows you to use normal C# naming conventions for your poco structure, which could look like this:

```
public class Root : Dictionary<string, Animal> {
}

public class Animal {
  public string Filename { get; set; }
  public long Size { get;set; }
  public IList<Region> Regions { get;set; }
  [JsonExtensionData]
  public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get;set; }
}

public class Region {
  public ShapeAttribute ShapeAttributes { get; set; }
  public RegionAttribute RegionAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class ShapeAttribute {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IList<int> AllPointsX { get; set; }
  public IList<int> AllPointsY { get; set; }
}

public class RegionAttribute {
  [JsonProperty("Animal")]
  public string Animal { get;set; }
}
```

This has 2 caveats, the `Animal` property inside the `RegionAttribute` class, should be defined directly (as it capitalized), and for all remaining unspecified properties (like `file_attributes`) I added an `IDictionary<string, object> Properties` that would hold all non-specified properties on the `Animal` object.

I provided a sample based on your data in [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MRGXeA)